# How to check then define a function if is not defined in other part of the code or other dot-sourced scripts

Tags: powershell

I am building a PowerShell script that might run or called in variety of different setup.

I need to define a function (say `f`) if it is not defined anywhere else.

How to check then define a function if is not defined in other part of the code or other dot-sourced scripts?

Comment: How about a try catch using `Get-Command f`

Comment: `if (-not (Get-Command -CommandType Function | ? name -eq 'f')) { define function f here }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Command -Name f -ErrorAction Stop` will throw an `ObjectNotFound` exception if there is no cmdlet, function, or “operable program” (executable file) `f`. You can use this in a [`try {...} catch {...}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2) construct to decide whether you need to define it - but be careful about [scope rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2).

A `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException` (which is the ‘parent’ type of an `ObjectNotFound`) is not normally a terminating error, so you need the `-ErrorAction Stop` to force it to become a terminating error that can be handled in the `try {...} catch {...}`.